# Se cambian las tildes por comas y las eñes(ñ) por simbolos, MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy utilizando xampp, tuve un problema y tuve que desinstalarlo y volverlo a instalar, pero cuando lo instalé de nuevo y cree mi base de datos, me surgió el problema de que al guardar un dato con tildes o eñes y visualizarlo en phpmyadmin o en mi aplicación web me los cambia por otros símbolos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al visualizarlos por consola, me aparecen bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté con el cotejamiento `utf8_spanish_ci`, `utf8_general_ci` y `latin1_swedish_ci`

PD: El segundo valor de mi tabla lo puse solo para hacer la prueba con las eñes (ñ).

Comment: Cuando dices que intentaste esos cotejamientos, fue sólo en la BD? Cuál es la codificación del archivo con los datos? No sabemos tampoco cuál era el cotejamiento de la BD origen.

Comment: Lo modifique en el phpmyadmin, desde los campos, las tablas y hasta toda la base de datos

Comment: ¿Desde dónde estás alimentando esos datos?. ¿Un formulario con php? Si fuera así, luego de establecida la conexión con la BD, coloca `$nombre_conexion->set_charset("utf8");` Mira esta referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610293/1545868

Comment: En este caso desde consola, necesito meter varios registros de ese modo

Comment: Hice una aplicación web con angular 7 que envía los datos a través de un servidor Express a mi base de datos MySQL, en ese caso no hay ningún problema, los guarda tal y como lo introduzco, el problema es que hay algunas tablas en las que debo insertar aproximadamente 2,000 registros a través de consola